Flutter library import issue when targeting multiple platforms
TLDR; I'm building a Flutter app that has some Dart code and some Native code. It plays a video using the native players of the host platform (Media3 for Android, AVPlayer for iOS, and ShakaPlayer for Web). The native view is inserted into Flutter using PlatformViewLink (for Android and iOS) as for the web I'm using PlatformViewRegistry and HtmlElementView.
So the issue is that since I'm importing dart:web_ui and other stuff to build the web part of the app, the app compiles when I target web, but fails to compile when I target the other platforms.

I tried to do a conditional import like so
export 'handler_mobile.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) 'handler_mobile.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'handler_web.dart'; 

This no longer works in Flutter 3.19
How can I solve this?
